# BuddyPress - Auto join group

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I wanna automatically add new registered user to corresponding group by Buddypress.

Here is my code put in the theme's functions.

```
    function automatic_group_membership( $user_id ) {

       if( !$user_id ) return false;

        $join_group = xprofile_get_field_data(2, $user_id);  // 2 is xprofile field_id

        // conditional
        if ($join_group == "Group1") // Group Name
            $group_id = 3; // Group id

        // action
        groups_accept_invite( $user_id, $group_id );
    }

    add_action( 'bp_core_activated_user', 'automatic_group_membership' );
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I figure out this problem?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/imath/59875514ff46ba5e191b

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: No errors. It just can not add new users to existing group

Comment: Sorry for pitching in a bit late, but I want to achieve just that, without relying on any plugin. Did you try the same code without the conditional, that is, just `groups_accept_invite( $user_id, 3 );` to see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

Join a specific group on user activation:

```
function auto_join_group( $user_id ) {
    if( !$user_id ) return false;
    $group_id = 7;
    groups_join_group( $group_id, $user_id );
}
add_action( 'bp_core_activated_user', 'auto_join_group' );
```

As for the logic of whatever is a "corresponding group", I'll let the OP figure that one out!